# What is the efficient way to check whether x is multiple of n or not?

Tags: java, if-statement

Java Code:

```
if(x !=0 && x!= n && x!= 2*n .... x!= n*n){ 
    //do something here
}
```

Is there any better way of writing this code instead of this long form?

The code basically checks if **X != n * Y where, Y = any natural number(0-N)**.

Comment: Are you seeking for short code or efficient code?

Comment: @maetsus in this case most efficient code is quite short!

Comment: Check out my answer below, it's both short code and extremely efficient because it uses the modulus operator (%) instead of a loop.

Comment: @ParkerHalo I asked OP that which one he is looking for. If the solution is known before, what is the need of asking?

Comment: No existing answer handled the case of `n=0` where modulus is used. I handled it in my answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could encapsulate that functionality in a private method:

```
if (isDividableBy(x, n)) {
    //...
}
```

with the method:

```
private boolean isDividableBy(int x, intn) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (x == i*n)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You could make this more efficient if you use the modulo operator (%) but then the code becomes less readable!

The short version would be:

```
if (x%n != 0 || x < 0 || x > n*n) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: your `isDividableBy()` function would never return if `x != 0`.

Comment: You might want to increment i if you don't want to create an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

Using a loop would make more sense :

```
boolean isProd = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= n && !isProd; i++)
    isProd = (x == i * n);
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to confirm `X is not a multiple of n`:

```
float a = x * 1.0 / n;

if( Math.round(a) != a ) {
    // do something
}
```

And plus the condition that `when X < n*n, X is not a multiple of n`:

```
if( (x/n) > n || (x/n) < 0 || x % n != 0 ) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So basicly you would want to check if `x != 0` and if `x` isn´t a multiple of `n`. 
If that´s the case you could simply make use of the remainder operator like this:

```
private boolean is_valid(long n, long x) {
    // This condition will be valid if n is not a multiple of n
    // and if the divisor of X/n is greater then n
    if(x % n != 0 || n < x/n) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to set a flag when any of your conditions meet.

```
int n=10;
int x=2; 
boolean doThis = true;
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
if(x==i*n) {
    doThis =false;
    break;      
}           
}   

if(doThis) {
System.out.println("do this!");         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
if( (n==0&&x!=0) || (n!=0 &&(x<0||x>n*n||x%n!=0)) {
    //do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice solution without a loop:

```
if ((x < n*n) && (x%n != 0)){
    ...
}
```

The first check is to make sure x is not larger than the upper limit of n*n.

Then the modulus operator (%) gives the remainder of x/n. If the remainder is 0, then x is equal to some multiple of n and will not enter the if statement.

Comment: This will not do what the OP intended... why would you make sure that "x is not larger than the upper limit of n*n" ?

Comment: The last condition in his code was x!= n*n, which I assumed was an upper limit. But if he only meant for that to be an arbitrary "large number" and he really wants any multiple n from 0 to infinity, then the first check can be taken off and just use: if (x%n != 0) {... That will cover every integer multiple of n with no upper limit.